# LIBGDX ios simulator crash. LibGDX / Robovm compiles for 64bit instead of 32bit. What should I do?

Tags: libgdx, ios-simulator, assets, robovm

My libgdx app starts up on ios simulator and shows ios intro libgdx pic, then crashes.

I get:

```
[ERROR] Session could not be started: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "Unable to run app in Simulator" UserInfo=0x7f853960ff60 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8539464ff0 "Failed to lookup the process ID of se.myapp.IOSLauncher after successful launch.  Perhaps it crashed after launch.", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An error was encountered while running (Domain = NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 3), NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to run app in Simulator}
```

Seems to be related to trying to run 64bit on iPhone 4s, where it is not supported. Does anyone know how to turn off 64bit for robovm in libgdx?

If I change the ios-sim command:

/Users/macuser/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.robovm.eclipse.ui/robovm-1.4.0/bin/ios-sim launch /Users/macuser/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.robovm.eclipse.ui/build/myapp-ios/myapp-ios/ios/**x86_64**/IOSLauncher.app --timeout 90 --unbuffered --devicetypeid "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s, 8.0" --stdout /var/folders/ml/zdhkbw3x0g9550pq9mgfrcsw0000gn/T/robovm-stdout-6250612031367207111.fifo --stderr /var/folders/ml/zdhkbw3x0g9550pq9mgfrcsw0000gn/T/robovm-stderr-5592986297298678222.fifo --setenv ROBOVM_LAUNCH_MODE=release --args -rvm:log=warn

To:

/Users/macuser/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.robovm.eclipse.ui/robovm-1.4.0/bin/ios-sim launch /Users/macuser/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.robovm.eclipse.ui/build/myapp-ios/myapp-ios/ios/**x86**/IOSLauncher.app --timeout 90 --unbuffered --devicetypeid "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s, 8.0" --stdout /var/folders/ml/zdhkbw3x0g9550pq9mgfrcsw0000gn/T/robovm-stdout-6250612031367207111.fifo --stderr /var/folders/ml/zdhkbw3x0g9550pq9mgfrcsw0000gn/T/robovm-stderr-5592986297298678222.fifo --setenv ROBOVM_LAUNCH_MODE=release --args -rvm:log=warn

It works with the old robovm. But for the new version it seems those directories aren't even built at all, so it fails.

Where should I specify the architecture? There is:

```
<arch>thumbv7</arch>
```

in robovm.xml but it doesn't seem to do anything?
Has this anything to do with the eclipse integration plugin (I am running from eclipse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found out (after about 12 hours of digging)!

I looked in the wrong place all the time. The solution is (in **eclipse**) to go to **Run Configurations / iOS Simulator App / Choose a device and select 32-bit (x86)**.